# Can't type in the ipython console after code has been saved

Tags: python, ipython

On the spyder python software, whenever I save my code, I lose the ability to type into ipython.
New user here, not sure if this is just some weird setting but I haven't had this problem on any of my universities computers, its only on my laptop I am having this issue.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda but the same problem persists.

Before code is saved:
[image: Before code is saved]

After code is saved:
[image: After]

As you can see in the second picture I lose the ability to type in the console. How can I fix this?

Edit:

The code

```
def f(x):
    return x**4-2*x+1
i=1
while i<=10:
    def I(a,b):
        n=1000
        h=(2)/nd
        x=a
        total=0
        while x<=b:
            sum=f(x)+f(x+h)
            total=sum+total
            x=x+h
            return total*(h/2)
```

Comment: What do you mean, "after code has been saved"? That `runfile` doesn't save code, it *runs* code; presumably it is waiting for that script to complete.

Comment: I have added the code, I ran the same code at university although I didnt have this problem.

Comment: Hit the red stop square in the upper right corner. the code is running, which is why you cant make changes. once you hit that button it will be editable again

Comment: That code will never terminate